# Calculate the distance between each GPS points of two lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, distance, geopandas, euclidean-distance

Let assume that we have a pandas dataframe contain of two columns as ("longitude" and "latitude"), which split by (comma) for example:

| longitude | latitude |
| --- | --- |
| [116.415642, 116.41832, 116.418976, 116.419029, 116.421791, 116.426666, 116.429077, 116.43174, 116.434334, 116.436806] | [39.897133, 39.897213, 39.898766, 39.900906, 39.900486, 39.90062, 39.900681, 39.900738, 39.900749, 39.900818] |

I am stuck with how can I calculate the distance between each long/lat point to get a new column as distance gap (KM) between each of them as (''gap_dist''). The outputs should be like:

[image]

I have found numerous tutorials just to find the distance between a single pair of coordinates (source and destination). So what is the best way to achieve this in python?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your reference point? you have to calculate the distance between (x,y) and a reference (x0, y0). judging by your result, is your first point the (x0, y0)?

Comment: you want the haversine function, there are many example here on stack. Let me know if your search doesnt give you what you want

Comment: @user3184950 Yes I need haversine or euclidean distance, I can calculate both of them for example given (one to one point), my current case (list of points). Any idea?

Comment: If you format your data in easy copy pastable form, I can show a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the gap between each point and the first point, it goes as this:

```
from math import dist
lats   = [float(lat)  for lat  in df['latitude'][0]]
longs  = [float(long) for long in df['longtitude'][0]]
p0 = [lats[0], longs[0]]
dists = [dist(p0, [x,y]) for x, y in zip(lats, longs)]
```

Comment: Hello @aSaffary Thanks for your reply, I try to do it, but actually I get this error (TypeError: must be real number, not list), i thought it because of "p0" is list of string. So how can we convert list of string to list of float?

Comment: <ipython-input-128-56cd61e98226> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 longs  = df2['longitude']
      4 p0 = [lats[0], longs[0]]
----> 5 dists = [dist(p0, [x,y]) for x, y in zip(lats, longs)]

TypeError: must be real number, not list

Comment: @M_Fatih89 i think the problem is that the lats and longs variables are not lists, since your field contains a list of values, then lats could be a list of lists. i edited the answer to get the first row of data frame only.

Comment: print(type(lats[0]))
print(type(longs[0]))
print(type(lats[0][0]))
print(type(longs[0][0]))

output:
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>

Comment: in your question they're float, but now it seems they're string. just call float on them before using them like : lats = [float(i) for i in df['latitude'][0]]

Comment: Yes, now it works fine, thanks. Can I save it as column for all dataset?

Comment: the result will be a list, since each one of your fields is a list, then it'd make sense to save this as a field.

Comment: you are right, so I should use for loop to apply it for all the dataset, right?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, the zero index in ['latitude'][0] is picking only the first row of data, you need to iterate rows and do this to every row instead.